# Spawn Process from a C# Windows Service

Tags: c#, windows, service

Well, Im trying to spawn a process from inside a thread spawned by a Windows Service. The goal being to read the output and printing to the window in focus -- where cursor is. Probably a bad idea, I don't know i'm not a c# programmer

Anywho spawning the process works when I call the function itself, but not when it's called inside a running service. Is starting a process inside a service possible?

```
Process proc = new Process();
                proc.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\file.bat";
                proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
                proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
                proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;

                proc.Start();

                String outputMessage = proc.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
                proc.WaitForExit();
```

Comment: It is probably related to the permisions of the user the service is running as. What happens this code runs in the service do you get any kind of error

Comment: No errors, it starts fine. Just nothing happens.

Comment: What is in the outputMessage variable after the process runs in the service.

Comment: @stefan, that setting no longer exists on Windows Vista and higher. Services now run in their own desktop, which has no access to the user desktop.

Comment: Yea I see that now. This is all going into XP!! Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Starting a process from a service is certainly possible. However, services run inside session 0 and have no desktop. Interactive users run their desktops in a different session. Consequently it is very challenging to get a process up and running inside an interactive session when starting from a service.

For an illustration of the issues involved, and how tricky it is to get right, read this: [Launching an interactive process from Windows Service in Windows Vista and later](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/winsdk/archive/2009/07/14/launching-an-interactive-process-from-windows-service-in-windows-vista-and-later.aspx).

The simplest approach would be to separate your service into two distinct parts. One part runs as a service, and the other part runs as a windowless process in the interactive session. These two processes can communicate by whatever IPC mechanism you prefer. When the service wants to start a process it simply sends a message to its other half in the interactive session to request that the new process is started.

Comment: Ahh cool, I saw the "Allow Service to Interact with Desktop" box. Checked it and I can see now that things are being spawned. Sweet

Comment: You must be on XP. That setting won't help on Vista and up.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to interact between your GUI and show some sort of feedback to the user, why don't you implement a WCF interface over a named pipe.  Host it in your service and provide a "status" API or even functions if required.  That way you can provide a gui to any user on the system and the service stays clean.

But as @David Heffernan mentioned, its not really recommended to create gui from windows services, and from Vista onwards they create in the Session 0 context.